# How to invoke a function in child component from parent?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

So my parent component has a "Next" button. When I tap this "Next" button, I want this to invoke a function in the child that passes data to the global state. What's the best way to go about this? Here's some dummy code:

```
<Parent />


this.state{
  change: 'Two'
}

functionOne(){
  this.setState({
    change: 'One'
  })
}

render(){
  return(
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity 
        onPress={ () => this.functionOne() }>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}


<Child />

this.state {
  data1: "I"
  data2: "WANT"
  data3: "THIS"
}

thisOne(){
 this.props.toGlobal(this.state)
}
```

Comment: A parent executing a function on the child is anti-pattern. Not saying the child shouldn't have event handlers, but they should either be handling local state or bubbling up

Comment: So the data should be passed from the Child to the Parent and from the Parent, run the `this.props.toGlobal(data)`  when I tap the Next button?

Comment: No, the expression to learn is `data down, actions up`

Comment: Thanks, found a medium article, I'll spend some time on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a ref on the child component and call the function from the parent.

```
// Parent
render(){
  return(
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity 
        onPress={ () => this.child.functionOne() }>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Child ref={child => this.child = child} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass down the handler to the child and then call it on the parent with whatever values you wish to update as parameters.

Example:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      change: 'Two'
    };

    this.toGlobal = this.toGlobal.bind(this);
  }

  toGlobal(values) {
    // update global state with value
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <Child
        toGlobal={this.toGlobal} />
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state {
      data1: "I"
      data2: "WANT"
      data3: "THIS"
    };

    this.thisOne = this.thisOne.bind(this);
  }

  thisOne() {
    this.props.toGlobal(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={this.thisOne} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```